# Is it necessary to assign a string to a variable before comparing it to another?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, variables

I want to compare the value of an `NSString` to the string "Wrong".  Here is my code:

```
NSString *wrongTxt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Wrong"];
if( [statusString isEqualToString:wrongTxt] ){
     doSomething;
}
```

Do I really have to create an NSString for "Wrong"?

Also, can I compare the value of a `UILabel`'s `text` to a string without assigning the label value to a string?

Comment: By the way, you're wasting time with initWithFormat, you can change    
NSString *wrongTxt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Wrong"]; to 
NSString *wrongTxt = @"Wrong"; 
 Only bother with initWithFormat if you're going to try to calculate a string from other inputs e.g. 
NSString *wrongTxt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ was wrong %d times",craigString, wrongCount];

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> Do I really have to create an NSString for "Wrong"?

No, why not just do:

```
if([statusString isEqualToString:@"Wrong"]){
    //doSomething;
}
```

Using `@""` simply creates a string literal, which is a valid `NSString`.

> Also, can I compare the value of a UILabel.text to a string without assigning the label value to a string?

Yes, you can do something like:

```
UILabel *label = ...;
if([someString isEqualToString:label.text]) {
    // Do stuff here 
}
```

Comment: That works.  I guess I just have buggy code.  It was throwing an exception before.

Comment: To elaborate: label.text *IS* a string, so of course you don't need to create a string from it for the comparison.

Answer (score 26):

```
if ([statusString isEqualToString:@"Wrong"]) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks wevah. Perspx was 1 sec faster.

Answer (score 8):

Brian, also worth throwing in here - the others are of course correct that you don't need to declare a string variable.  However, next time you want to declare a string you don't need to do the following:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SomeText"];
```

Although the above does work, it provides a retained NSString variable which you will then need to explicitly release after you've finished using it.

Next time you want a string variable you can use the "@" symbol in a much more convenient way:

```
NSString *myString = @"SomeText";
```

This will be autoreleased when you've finished with it so you'll avoid memory leaks too...

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was wondering about that. I often see string variables that are objective c objects, but they are never released.  Thanks!

Comment: The hint is in the "alloc" bit.  If you use an Alloc (or Copy) then you have to specifically release.  If you don't, the convention is that the object will be already set to autorelease.

Comment: Yes, although it can contain `new` or `copy` for example `newObject` (from `NSDictionaryController`) or `mutableCopy` (from `NSObject`) http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the NSString class methods which will also create an autoreleased instance and have more options like string formatting:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"];
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc %d efg", 42];
```