# If-Statement for String/Int

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my if clause always runs into the else statement? Whats the fault?

```
        NSLog([[category objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue]); // Traces 15
        if ([[category objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue] == "15") {
            result.isExternal = YES;
        } else {
            result.isExternal = NO;
        }
```

thanks for helping

Comment: what is the type of the object held by your dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change

```
[[category objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue]
```

to

```
[[[category objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"15"]
```

And as for comparing that `stringValue` how you are, you need to do `== @"15"` as `"15"` isn't a string unless an `@` is infront.

Comment: Thanks, but I still run into the else statement.

Comment: Then try comparing the `intValue` like so: `[[[category objectForKey:@"id"] intValue] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15]]`

Comment: `intValue` returns an `int`, which means you can do `[... intValue] == 15`

Comment: Gah, was just editing my original answer, forgot you should do what you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use isEqualToString
[Is it necessary to assign a string to a variable before comparing it to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302985/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Your "if" statement is comparing two C strings with "==". You should use strcmp for that.
If your function returns an objective C string, you should use @"15", and the correct comparison function.