# OR function in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

is there an OR function in Objective-C?

for example:

```
if(string1 == string2 || string3 == string 4)
```

`||` doesnt seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error? What is it? `||` is a perfectly valid operator in Objective C. You can't compare strings with `==` though. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302985/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

|| is a valid Objectivc-C and C Operator. It should work.

Try is code:

```
if([string1 isEqualToString:string2] || [string3 isEqualToString:string4]) 
{
}
```

Comment: sorry for editing but naming a string `string` could have been misleading :-)

Answer (score 1):

The or-operator `||` works fine, but the `==` operator doesn't work for C-strings nor for `NSString` if you want to test for string-equality. As written you only test for the pointers being equal.

Instead use:

- `strcmp()` for C-style strings
- `-isEqualToString:` for `NSString`

Comment: The only issue here is strcmp will return 0 if the strings are equal, you'd have to invert the checks.

Comment: No reason to be using strcmp anyway.

Comment: @ZaBlanc: Could you be more specific?