# Parsing json incorrect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

i'm parsing something from the Apple JSON (the rating of the app) and i tried something like:

```
 if ([StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] == @"4.5") {
        NSLog(@"xx");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"xxx");
    }
```

The App has a rating of 4.5 and if i do

```
NSlog (@"%@", [StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"]);
```

The output is : 4.5

but when i run the script the NSlog in the first code's output is "xxx" does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

Comparing strings, which are essentially pointers to instances of the NSSring class, is erroneous, as two identical-content strings can have a different memory address. Use

```
if ([[StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] isEqualToString:@"4.5"])
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this:

```
if ([StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] == @"4.5")
```

You need to do:

```
if ([[StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] isEqualToString:@"4.5"])
```

That's assuming it's a string. If it's an `NSNumber` then do:

```
if ([[StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] floatValue] == 4.5f)
```

(Although be [careful about comparing equality of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328475/should-we-compare-floating-point-numbers-for-equality-against-a-relative-error))

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302985/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-objective-c) for more information on string equality.

Answer (score 4):

Use `isEqualToString`:

```
if ([[StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] isEqualToString:@"4.5"]) {
    NSLog(@"xx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value for `averageUserRating` is an `NSNumber`, you should convert it to a formatted `NSString` first then compare it to the `@"4.5"` string literal:

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f", [[StoreParse objectForKey:@"averageUserRating"] floatValue]] isEqualToString:@"4.5"])
```